# Ubuntu default terminal not working

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, 19.04, bashrc

I have the new `Ubuntu 19.04,` I tried writing some alias and it's my first time however the aliases did not work so i cleared them, I think in the process I might have tempered with the .bashrc file, so on trying my terminal after that point it comes up and goes off, in a couple of milliseconds, downloaded `powershell` and works fine however I'm not comfortable with it. Any way to fix the terminal without having to reinstall the OS?

I've tried Resetting the `.bashrc` file and did not solve the issue, also tried purging gnome-terminal and updating gnome, still no changes to the terminal however I noticed some good changes in my OS,

Tried typing `gnome-terminal` in  `xterm` interface and got the following message

[image: Image here]

Comment: Apparently the error isn't from the .bashrc file, restored the default one following @byte-commander 's answer. Still the terminal does not respond

Comment: Thanks @starkus Done all these as you suggest however still does not work

Comment: Thanks, Still does not work, I'll resolve to reinstalling my OS

Comment: Oh, any useful step by step article to achieve this?

Comment: @none Can you still open `xterm` (different, more basic terminal emulator)? If so, try typing `gnome-terminal` in there to see if you get any diagnostic output.

Comment: @ByteCommander on typing that, I got the following https://imgur.com/a/C8I6rYE

Comment: @none was that everything? it looks cropped. Also please rather [edit] your question and add the output as plain, code-formatted text there. Thanks.

Comment: @starkus Thanks so much man, I really appreciate

Comment: @ByteCommander updated the post as suggested, however I cannot copy from xterm , so i took another screen shot, should be clarer

Answer (score 3):

To revert any modifications you might have done to your `.bashrc` file, just delete it and replace it with a fresh copy of the default `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks! Done that and managed to save the new .bashrc file however my terminal still does not respond, I might have missed the error! Any other possible cause to this?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a complaint about Chrome Remote Desktop settings some odd values, and causing "terminal" to fail.

The cure there was

gnome-shell --replace